# Update conference details without date be required

Tags: php, laravel

I have the `update()` to udpate the conference details.

If the user fills in the form the name of the conference and dont fill the start_date and end_date fields it appears an error "InvalidArgumentException Data missing" in the Carbon.php file. The start_date and end_date are not required fields.

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'start_date' => 'nullable|date_format:"d F Y - H:i"',
            'end_date' => 'nullable|date_format:"d F Y - H:i"|after_or_equal:start_date',
        ];

        $customMessages = [
            'name.required' => 'The field name is required.',
            'start_date.date_format' => 'The field start_date dont have a valid format.',
            'end_date.date_format' => 'The field end_date dont have a valid format.',
            'end_date.after_or_equal' => 'The end_date must be after start_date.'
        ];


        $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);

        $conference = Conference::find($id);

        $conference->name = $request->name;
        $conference->start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->start_date);
        $conference->end_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->end_date);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I changed to:

```
$conference->start_date = ($request->start_date) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->start_date) : '';
        $conference->end_date =   ($request->start_date) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->end_date) : '';
```

But also dont works, because if the user dont enters any date instead of appears a success message it shows the other validation messages related to the date:

```
The field start_date dont have a valid format.
The field end_date dont have a valid format.
The end_date must be after start_date.
```

Comment: By `var_dump($request)` check what the request is,when user do not enter data.

Comment: Its "  "start_date" => null
  "end_date" => null".

Comment: try `$conference->start_date = !empty($request->start_date) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->start_date) :  '' ;`

Comment: Also is this a valid format 'd F Y - H:i' ?